How does a sphere roll on ground, no really?
Everyone knows this right!
Consider the ground to be the $xy$ plane and consider gravity to be acting along the $-z$ direction. If a sphere (mass $M$, radius $R$) is placed on the ground and given initial velocity $(v, 0, 0)$ (centre of mass) and initial angular velocity $(0, v/R, 0)$ it will start pure rolling. We can verify that the bottom most point will have velocity $(v, 0, 0) + (0, v/R, 0)×(0,0,-R) = (0, 0, 0)$
So there is no slipping, hence no friction. The only forces on the body are the normal force of the ground and gravity, which cancel out giving no acceleration and both individually give no torque. So this motion continues forever. Just some introductory rigid body mechanics.
Except, what if we change the initial conditions. Say give the body a velocity $(v, 0, 0)$ still but give it an angular velocity of $(0, w/R, k)$ for any $k$ we want. The preceeding analysis is unchanged! The cross product is not affected by $k$ so there is still no slipping, no friction, no torque. So this motion should continue forever!
But that's crazy right!. How can you give a ball an "off-axis" spin and expect it to continue moving in a straight line. But the math seems to work out.
So it this true? Is this just something that's hidden away in introductory rigid body motion courses? Is there some intuitive way to see it?

Something to think about: what happens if we give the ball a spin about the $z$-axis only, with zero COM velocity?

I can't see any problem with the rollin in the third direction, if you have no friction on the ground or by the air.

It's a top! Wait, are you suggesting that off axis rolling is a "superposition" of normal rolling and top motion? @d_b

@trula I also see no problem with this motion, but I find it extremely weird that it's not covered in intro to rigid body dynamics courses (as far as I could tell), considering how simple it seems.

The spinning of a ball around the vertical is just not interesting, why should one treet any trivial case, late you will have real tops,  and it gets more interesting.

In practice, the sphere would squish a little, so rather than a single point there would be a circular patch of contact with the plane. Then different parts of the patch would be rolling at slightly different speeds, and you would get a torque. That's why your intuition tells you that the sphere should change direction.
When you take the limit of infinite hardness, so the contact patch shrinks to a point, the frictional torque vanishes but the frictional force (if there is any) remains.
Similarly, if you have a sphere spinning on a vertical axis on a single point of contact, there can be no frictional torque, because all frictional forces pass through the same point. The ball would spin forever. In practice, with a contact patch, forces on either side of the patch would be in opposite directions, and you would get torque that would slow the spin.

Intuitively, the sphere can be stationary (zero cm velocity) with a spin around the z axis -- like a spinning top with point contact.  If there is spin about the x or y axes, then it must roll somehow if there is no slip.  So superimposing a pure z-axis spin doesn't affect the rolling motion, as you say.

I find this motion difficult to visualize. It feels that the sphere should just start moving in a non straight line after some time. Is there some good visual aid to see this motion?

In the real world, it probably would deflect a little.  Between airflow effects and non-ideal contact, there would likely be some Magnus-like effect.  So I think your instinct is correct.   But in the mathematical abstraction there is no effect.  Not sure about visualization.

A friend I know, not on this website,.came up with a beautiful visualization, consider 2 planes at an angle, like a V shape and set a sphere rolling between them. Now we can see that the sphere pure rolls on both planes, confirming that the line joining the Tangency points is the IAOR. Now orient this setup to keep one of the planes as ground. Since it's pure rolling, friction does not matter and the inclined plane contributes no normal reaction (since COM has no horizontal acceleration), so it can be removed without affecting the motion. And we have off-axis pure rolling.
